# CSS selector to match elements with at least two instances of a class, excluding the first instance for each of them

Tags: css

I need a CSS selector that can find all the elements that have more instances of the same class, except the first one of each class. That classes are generated dynamically.
The dynamic generation is the biggest difference with other related questions available in Stack Overflow.

This elements will be siblings in the documents.

My AngularJS template is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items" class="row-{{item.productId}}">...</tr>
```

And so the document HTML will be something like this:

```
<tr class="row-1">...</tr>
<tr class="row-2">...</tr>
<tr class="row-1">...</tr>
<tr class="row-1">...</tr>
<tr class="row-3">...</tr>
<tr class="row-3">...</tr>
```

I expect that the CSS rule will select only elements with more than one occurrence per class, except the first occurrence of them. So, in that example the 3rd, 4th and 6th tr elements

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Question not clear are you trying to select all tr elements apart from the first or only .row-1 elements apart from the first?

Comment: Wrap them with a `container` class for example and use:`.container .row-1:not(:first-child) {/*Css rule*/}`

Comment: @tomas I am trying to select all elements that have more occurrences of the same class, except the first occurrence. In that example so I would select the .row-1 elements except the first one, because other tr elements have only one occurrence per class

Comment: Then Ethan Vu's comment should help. Essentially every class apart from the first will be the same as saying where there's more than occurrence.

Comment: @EthanVu That's not the way `nth-child/type` works....I can't differentiate by *class*